# VSCode: need help trying to import requests for a program to run, but the module cannot be found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, python-requests

Im new to stack overflow and I had a question about importing requests in vscode. I looked through other stack overflow questions and found that I have 2 versions of python for some reason AND python v3.9.1 can run pip to install requests but python v3.6.4 cannot install pip and keeps giving a module not found error.

I originally thought the obvious answer to this was to switch my python interpreter to 3.9.1 and my program should theoretically run, but even when I am on v3.9.1 I am unable to run requests and am given a module not found error

I suspect it could be the multiple versions but I honestly have no clue and would appreciate any help. Some of the screenshots are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkwVW.png)

Comment: every `Python` should have own `pip` with version number - `pip3.6`, `pip3.9` - which install module to this version. Or you can use `python3.6 -m pip ...` and `python3.9 -m pip ...` to install for different versions.

Comment: maybe you have two copy of `python v3.9.1` and one you run in console to install module , and second is used by `VSCode` and it doesn't have modules. In code you could run `print( sys.executable )` to see full path to used Python. And then you should use `/full/path/to/python -m pip ...` to install module in correct `Python`.